# Is there named scope's analog for Doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, named-scope, doctrine-orm

Does Doctrine2 have a features similar to ActiveRecord's [named scopes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-has-finder-functionality)?

Comment: Also Yii framework has they http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one baked into D2, but it probably wouldn't be too much of a stretch to implement a system similar to Yii's using Doctrine 2's [QueryBuilder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/query-builder/en) class, which allows you to construct a query in pieces, using a more programmatic approach.

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder;
 $qb->select('u')
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->where('active IS NOT NULL);
```

It appears that Yii's implementation stores query criteria in an array, and they are injected into the query when a named scope is used. You could easily do something similar that returns a QueryBuilder object with those params pre-loaded.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   private $_namedScopes;

   public getActiveUsersWhoLoggedInLastWeek()
   {
      // return a query builder for this model
      $qb = $this->_namedScopes->initScope();

      // start adding pre-defined criteria
      $qb = $this->_namedScopes->addScope($qb, 'active')
      $qb = $this->_namedScopes->addScope($qb, 'lastWeek');

      return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
}
```

There are probably several different ways to approach this, so that's just one quick example. The hard part would probably be figuring out how to handle criteria collisions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-750